# C++ maps: Access previous value of specific key

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map with multiple keys in an iteration. At each timestep, I would like to access the previous value of a specific key starting from the second timestep. There is a chance that my keys are not consecutive and that is causing issues.

For example if each iteration has the following:

```
key = 1 |  Val = 1
key = 1 |  Val = 2
key = 1 |  Val = 3
key = 2 |  Val = 10
key = 2 |  Val = 20
```

when I try to access key = 2 (on second iteration), I get last value of key 1 instead. (I need to get 10 but getting 3)

My try:

```
map<int, int > values
itlow=values.lower_bound(key);
itlow--;
if(itlow->first== key)
return itlow->second;
```

**Update**

If vals are vector then each key should hold multiple value:

```
map<int, vector<int>> values
itlow=values.lower_bound(key);
itlow--;
if(itlow->first== key)
return itlow->second;
```

Question: how would it access to the previous elements of the same key?

Comment: Can you please show content of the `map`? Your example data shows duplicated keys, so very unclear what you expect to happen. (Obviously you know that [map](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)  property is "Unique keys:
No two elements in the container can have equivalent keys.")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the keys are suppose to be duplicate at each timestep: lets say time = 1 then key = 1 val = 1, time = 2 then key = 1 and val = 2. Until time = x then key = 2 but when try to access its value, it picks the previous val from the other key. Hope this clarifies

Comment: So your `values` map is {{1:3} , {2:20}}, right? Where do you expect 10 to come from if you *only* have two values 3 and 20? Or maybe your question is "how to store list of historical data in a map for a given key"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was on an impression that maps already store list of historical data? if thats the case then you are correct, if it is storing in a historical data then how would I access previous element of a specific key

Comment: Maps don't store historical data. When you set a new value for a key, the old value is gone, just as when you assign a new value to a variable. I'm curious what led you to believe that maps are more complicated than a simple mapping from key to value. Perhaps you were thinking of a multimap?

Comment: @rici I wonder if using multimap would resolve the issue?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. Multimap insert preserves insertion order for equal keys, iirc. If that's what you want, it might be fine.

Comment: multimap will fill up with many values that have the same key.  Which is fine if there aren't many iterations.  But if this is going to do many iterations thenyou will use a lot of memory.  You might be better to use a `std::map<int,std::queue<int>>` because then you can keep only two of each key (the current and the last)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thank you!! - then how can I access to the last value(previous) of the specific key and not the last overall stored value in my map? (original question)

Comment: When are the values put into the map?  If you can just get the value before updating it that would work.  If you have to update it first then you need a map that can store multiple values for each key (like a multimap or a map of queues).    It will be hard to write an answer without seing how and when you stick the values in.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah values have to be updated first and in each iteration, the previous value of the matching key to a separate logic be chosen. I tried to recreate the scenario as best as I could

Comment: Don't use a map of vectors - it will store all previous values which is the same thing multimap would do.  Eventually you will use lots of memory when really you only need the current and the immediately previous values.

Comment: What do you do in the very first iteration before there are any previous values?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah if t=0 at t=1 I need values at t=0 to do calculation. so at first time I'm just bypassing any code with a logic and counter and it goes for the logic at second iteration

Comment: What about this:  It inserts before retrieving and has an if statement that checks the size to make sure there is a previous item.  https://onlinegdb.com/23OhUwDTS

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thank you so much!! I'll give it a shot and will let you know of my findings